# VBScript to Un-install windows application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, vbscript

I tried to uninstall the windows application exe which is already installed in my system using VBScript. But was not able to Uninstall the exe. Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

I tried with following code:

```vbs
Dim oReg, oShell, oFSO 
Dim UninstallString, ProductCode
Dim strComputer, colItems, objWMIService, objItem
Dim strKeyPath, subkey, arrSubKeys
strComputer = "." 

'********************************
'Enter Product Code Of The Application Here That You Want To Uninstall within the    Bracket 
ProductCode = "{XXXXC6BA-0F96-4E3B-BB14-211E2805XXXX}" 

'********************************

' Get scripting objects needed throughout script.
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

'**************************
UninstallString = "Database Upgrade Utility.exe /X" & ProductCode & " /qn" & "   /norestart"

Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002

Set oReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" &_ 
strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
oReg.EnumKey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, arrSubKeys

For Each subkey In arrSubKeys 

  IF subkey = ProductCode Then 
    oShell.Run UninstallString, 1, True
  End If

Next

Set oShell = Nothing
Set oReg = Nothing
```

MODIFIED CODE

```vbs
Dim oReg, oShell, oFSO 
Dim UninstallString, ProductCode
Dim strComputer, colItems, objWMIService, objItem
Dim strKeyPath, subkey, arrSubKeys
strComputer = "." 

'********************************
'Enter Product Code Of The Application Here That You Want To Uninstall within the Bracket 
ProductCode = "{4AE9C6BA-0F96-4E3B-BB14-211E2805227E}" 

'********************************

' Get scripting objects needed throughout script.
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

'**************************
UninstallString = """C:\Program Files\ASCO\DatabaseUpgradeUtility\ASCO Database Upgrade Utility.exe"" /X" & ProductCode & " /qn /norestart"
'UninstallString = "ASCO Database Upgrade Utility.exe /X" & ProductCode & " /qn" & " /norestart"
InputBox(UninstallString)
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002

Set oReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" &_ 
strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
oReg.EnumKey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, arrSubKeys

For Each subkey In arrSubKeys 

  'IF subkey = ProductCode Then 
  '.Run UninstallString, 1, True
  'End If
  IF subkey = ProductCode Then
    oShell.Run "%COMSPEC% /k " & UninstallString, 1, True
  End If

Next

Set oShell = Nothing
Set oReg = Nothing
```

tried the above and the path also trid with out double quotes also but both are not working. Please provide me if any thing that i have to change in the above script.

Comment: `..."Database Upgrade Utility.exe /X"...` looks like it's begging for quotes around the executable's name.

Comment: "Not working" is an insufficient problem description. How *execatly* is it "not working"? What output do you get in the `CMD` window? What is the return value of the command? Did you verify that it's being run at all?

Answer (score 0):

Your executable name has spaces in it, so you need to put double quotes around it, otherwise the shell object will try to run an executable `Database`, which cannot be found.

Change this line:

```vbs
UninstallString = "Database Upgrade Utility.exe /X" & ProductCode & " /qn" & "   /norestart"
```

into this:

```vbs
UninstallString = """Database Upgrade Utility.exe"" /X" & ProductCode & " /qn /norestart"
```

Also, make sure that the path to `Database Upgrade Utility.exe` is in the `PATH` environment variable. If it isn't, you need to run the executable with its full path.

```vbs
UninstallString = """C:\Program Files\ASCO\DatabaseUpgradeUtility\ASCO Database Upgrade Utility.exe"" /X" & ProductCode & " /qn /norestart"
```

If that doesn't work, check the following things:

- Is the `Run` statement executed in the first place? Change the conditional like this to see if the code actually goes into the `Then` branch:

  ```vbs
  IF subkey = ProductCode Then
    WScript.Echo "Subkey check OK."
    oShell.Run UninstallString, 1, True
  End If
  ```
- Does the uninstall command return an error code?

  ```vbs
  IF subkey = ProductCode Then
    rc = oShell.Run(UninstallString, 1, True)
    If rc <> 0 Then WScript.Echo "Command returned with status code " & rc & "."
  End If
  ```
- Does the uninstall command produce output on the console?

  ```vbs
  IF subkey = ProductCode Then
    oShell.Run "%COMSPEC% /k " & UninstallString, 1, True
  End If
  ```

Comment: I have tried the same with below modifications though its not uninstalling...UninstallString = "C:\Program Files\ASCO\DatabaseUpgradeUtility\ASCO Database Upgrade Utility.exe/X" & ProductCode & " /qn /norestart"

Comment: @user1000549 Again, a path with spaces **MUST** be put between double quotes. Please re-read my answer. Also, there's no space between the executable name and the `/X`.

Comment: tried like dis...UninstallString = "C:\Program Files\ASCO\DatabaseUpgradeUtility\""ASCO Database Upgrade Utility.exe"" /X" & ProductCode & " /qn /norestart"..not working..

Comment: Of course it's not working, because there's also a space in `Program Files`.

Comment: But If we give double quotes to Program files it will not execute..or else to full path we can put it in double quotes.

Comment: Try the 3rd code example from my updated answer. If that doesn't work, follow the instructions in the second half of my answer and update your question with your modified code and the findings from the debugging steps.